# Locate div with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am making a HTML program which has a main div that contains twelve small divs, which are moved to the left, and when they will have a line break they ought to be located in the position (0,0) of main div. I can't relocate the small divs, it always makes a line break at the end of the line.

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <style type="text/css">
        div.micapa {
            /* Decoration */
            background-color: red;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            border: 4px ridge orange;
            font-size: 26px;
            text-align: center;
            color: purple;
            font-weight: bold;
            line-height: 100px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            margin-right: 3px;

            /* Location */
            float: left;
            display: inline;
        }

        div#container {
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 100%;
            height: 108px;
            border: 5px ridge cyan;
        }       

    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".micapa").hover(function (){

                boxList = document.querySelectorAll(".micapa");

                marginIzqAux = $(this).css("margin-left");

                marginIzqLimit = parseInt($("body").css("width"));

                marginIzq = (((parseInt(marginIzqAux) + 100) % marginIzqLimit).toString()) + "px";

                $(".micapa:first-child").animate({
                    marginLeft: marginIzq,
                    marginTop: "0px"
                }, 2500, function() { 

                    i = boxList.length - 1;

                    while(i >= 0) {

                        if (marginIzqLimit < parseInt($(boxList[i]).css("margin-left"))) {
                            $(boxList[i]).css("margin-top", "-100px");
                            i = -1;
                        } else
                            --i;

                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="micapa">1</div>
            <div class="micapa">2</div>
            <div class="micapa">3</div>
            <div class="micapa">4</div>
            <div class="micapa">5</div>
            <div class="micapa">6</div>
            <div class="micapa">7</div>
            <div class="micapa">8</div>
            <div class="micapa">9</div>
            <div class="micapa">10</div>
            <div class="micapa">11</div>
            <div class="micapa">12</div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I carry on?

Thanks

Comment: `$(".micapa:first-child")` should be `$(".micapa:first")`

Comment: Here is the **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/6dphqyj5/)** but am not sure what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$(".micapa:first")
```

instead of

```
$(".micapa:first-child")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".micapa:first")
```

Or:

```
$(".micapa").first()
```

This is because the `.micapa` is not really the `first-child`.